# jdbc Statement or PreparedStatement without where

Tags: jdbc

If I don't have a WHERE clause in a query then should I use Statement or PreparedStatement. Which one will be efficient.

For Ex,

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM PERSON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prepared statement is precompiled to enhance efficiency. Also the database caches the statement which gains performance on later execution. Both can be of use even if you don't have variables in your statement. Especially if the statement is executed often.

If executed once or very seldomly I'd say a normal `Statement` is fine. Otherwise I would use a `PreparedStatement`. But there's no way of beeing sure about it without benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation of the JDBC driver. Some vendors save that statement in a cache, regardless if is a instance of `java.sql.Statement` or `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. For simplicity, you could use `java.sql.Statement`. On the other hand, if you plan to add a parameter and execute the statement several times (in the same connection), uses an instance of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`.

In the javadoc for [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) says:

> This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what has been mentioned by stonedsquirrel, another point is in future if you would want to add where condition then it is easy to make a change, all you need to add the following in your code

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ID, NAME FROM PERSON WHERE NAME= ?"); 
ps.setString(1, getName(""));
....
...
```

However if you are using `Statement`, then you need to make more changes in your code.

So by using `PreparedStatement` you will do minimal change if you need to add where conditions.

On the contrary by using `Statement`, it is quite easy to log or print the sql query, however if 
`PreparedStatement` is used, logging or printing sql statement is quite difficult or there are no direct approaches available.